# PG SQL 10 set default time zone to UTC

Tags: postgresql, timezone, postgresql-10

I need to change the database config to use UTC as the default for a PostgreSQL10 instance hosted on AWS RDS. I want it permanently changed at the database level and to never revert back to any other timezone no matter what.

I've tried running this, but it shows 0 updated rows:

```
ALTER DATABASE <my-db> SET timezone='UTC';
```

I've tried attaching a custom param group to the DB in RDS and modifying the entries like so (also rebooted after):

[image]

No matter what I do, when I run `select * from pg_settings where name = 'TimeZone';` or `SHOW timezone` it shows 'America/Chicago'.

It seems like this should be easy to do, but it is proving to be a challenge.

Comment: Did you reconnect?

Comment: I did, and I also rebooted the server..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store your timestamps in UTC and always want the database to send the data to the client in UTC as well, you should use the data type `timestamp without time zone`, which will not perform any time zone handling for you. That would be the simplest solution.

To convert the data, you could proceed like this:

```
SET timezone = 'UTC';
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER timestampcol TYPE timestamp without time zone;
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23739/timezone-parameter-in-postgresql-conf) question. Apparently PG stores the timestamp in UTC time but then converts it to the session time zone. From what I've gathered, since my timestamps don't include time zone information, I need to tell PG that the timezone being stored is UTC, and then convert that to whatever local time is needed, so something like this:

`SELECT my_timestamp_in_utc AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'America/Denver' as my_local_time
FROM my_table;`

This is a little verbose, but I'll go with it for now.